# CCK Nodereference individual imagefields

Tags: 7, entities, media

Is there a way to use a nodereference field on each individual image in a node? The images are CCK imagefields.

Comment: do you want to reference only the imagefields of nodes from another node?

Comment: Just the images inside of a node. A gallery node, with cck imagefields, 'tagging' Users in the photo similar to Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, no. A node reference as its name suggests references an entire node. I've not heard of a CCK type that references another CCK field, though I could find a reference to a module that did that for D5. If that's your requirement, my recommendation would be to use an image-as-node method.

Comment: But then you can't use something like Image FUpload, correct? For bulk uploading images into an album? Or can Image FUpload do that on its own?

Comment: @Kevin I don't know about Image FUpload, but I don't see anything on the project page suggesting it can't. I've used [Imagefield Import](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_import) before and it worked well, if not as snazzy as the Image FUpload flash doobry looks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a d5 module for that: [fieldreference](http://drupal.org/project/fieldreference). [Here](http://drupal.org/node/277592) you'll find a discussion about a d6 port. Maybe you could use [viewreference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference) or [noderefenrece in conbination with a view](http://drupal.org/node/289738) to solve your problem as stated in the discussion.